# Checking if the user is logged in, go to home directly, if not go to sign in

Tags: flutter

This is my main. I want to check if user is logged in then I want to go to home directly, if not go to sign in. I also have a splash screen, so I want to show it if the app is run for the first time. Im trying to implement but nothing goes right.

```
Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();

  Widget firstWidget;
  User? firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
  
  if (firebaseUser != null) {
    firstWidget = const HomeScreen();
  } else {
    firstWidget = const SplashScreen();
  }
  
  runApp(const MyApp());
}


class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Fema App',
      theme: theme(),
       home: firstWidget, //I tried to call first widget but I can't
      // We use routeName so that we dont need to remember the name
      //initialRoute: LoadPage.routeName,
      //initialRoute: HomeScreen.routeName,
      routes: routes,
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `NetworkImage('${user!.photoURL}')`. A network image will need a string value. Your code was trying to assign a value that can be null also. Now if you add it inside a string if user is null you still have an empty string.

Comment: thank you so much! May I ask you to check this, Im trying to check if a user is logged in, if a user is logged in , I want to skip the sign in screen, but if not go to sign in. I also have a splash screen.  I'll post it here.

Comment: After sign in save the user details in shared preferences. In splash page check the shared preferences and if logged in navigate the user to home page instead of sign in

Comment: Changing the question will result in irrelevant answer even though you accept it I may get down votes later.. Please keep the previous question and add the new one as a new question or a comment only. Thanks